# SignalR , How to call hub connection if hub class remain in Other library projects?

Tags: signalr

SignalR, How to call hub connection if hub class remain in Other library projects.

if the same project has public `class ChatHub : Hub{}` class then to call the connection we need to call `var hubNotif = $.connection.chatHub;`

But how I will get `var hubNotif` if my ChatHub class stay in different Class Library so that

```
Cannot read property 'client' of undefined using SignalR
```

error not occurred??

Comment: Please add more details on where you get your error and how are you implementing the client side.

Comment: Cannot read property 'client' of undefined using SignalR error throw from view page

Comment: Could you edit your question including the part that implements SignalR in your view page?